# How to reorder two lists of different size based on one list?

Tags: python, sorting, data-structures, list-comprehension

Given two different lists which share elements in common and have different size, how to reorder the second list based on the order of the elements of the first one? For example:

For:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'e', 'z', 'f']
b = ['a', 'f', 'b', 'z', 'g', 'h']
```

How to reorder list b into:

```
['a', 'b', 'z', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

For:

```
a = ['a', 'c', 'j', 'r' , 'p']
b = ['b', 'c', 'a']
```

How to reorder list b into:

```
['a', 'c', 'b']
```

So far I tried to:

```
[x for y, x in sorted(zip(a, b))]
```

However, I dont understand how to control the fact that the lists have different size. How could I reorder the second list based on the above restrictions?

Comment: Can `b` have duplicates? What happens then? Should a duplicate be moved to the end when `a` does not have a duplicate for it?

Comment: Thanks @trincot `b` can have, how should I solve that issue too?

Comment: It's up to you to tell us how you want such scenarios to play out. Can you edit your question where `b` and `a` have different frequencies of the same character, and provide the expected output for each example, so we can get a feel of what the logic is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide a key function to sort based on the index.

```py
a = ['a', 'b', 'e', 'z', 'f']
b = ['a', 'f', 'b', 'z', 'g', 'h']
from math import inf
res = sorted(b, key=lambda x: a.index(x) if x in a else inf)
print(res)
```

Comment: What about repeated items, would this also work? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JDo It should work; it will still sort based on the index in a. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 2):

you can map the list `a` elements to numerical order and then use python sort functionality of sorting number

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'e', 'z', 'f']
b = ['a', 'f', 'b', 'z', 'g', 'h']

order = {value:index for index, value in enumerate(a)}

solution = sorted(b, key=lambda x: order.get(x, len(b)+len(a)))
print(solution)
```

edit: @jferard corrected the case critera where how to order element if element in list b not present in list a.

Comment: For the case of repeated items in any of the lists would this work?

Comment: yes, but in that case, you need to decide for repeated item in list a, are we giving to preference of order to first occurence of element or last one, by default it is giving it to last one

Comment: Good that this avoids repeated calls to `a.index()` (which is O(N)).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it should be `order.get(x, len(a))` to place missing values after all known values of `a`. If `a` is longer than `b`, some values  will be be misplaced. Eg. `a = ['a', 'b', 'e', 'z', 'f', 'o', 'u', 'w']` and `b = ['a', 'f', 'b', 'z', 'w', 'h']` -> `['a', 'b', 'z', 'f', 'h', 'w']` but should be `['a', 'b', 'z', 'f', 'w', 'h']`.

Comment: @jferard yes you are right, updated solution

Answer (score 1):

You can create `dict` base index of `a`. This works for repeated item in `b` and for items do not exist in `a` we can use `itertools.count`.

```
from itertools import count

a = ['a', 'b', 'e', 'z', 'f']
b = ['a', 'a', 'f', 'f', 'b', 'z', 'z', 'g', 'h', 'g', 'h', 'e']


dct_enum = {j:i for (i, j) in enumerate(a)}
idx_not_exist = count(len(a))


dct_index = {}
for i in b:
    if i not in dct_index:
        if i in dct_enum:
            dct_index[i] = dct_enum[i]
        else:
            dct_index[i] = next(idx_not_exist)


sorted(b, key=dct_index.get)
# ['a', 'a', 'b', 'e', 'z', 'z', 'f', 'f', 'g', 'g', 'h', 'h']


# sort 'b' base:
# {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'e': 2, 'z': 3, 'f': 4, 'g':5, 'h':6}
```

By thanks [@Kelly Bundy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12671057/kelly-bundy), For a shorter approach, we can write like the below:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'e', 'z', 'f']
b = ['a', 'a', 'f', 'f', 'b', 'z', 'z', 'g', 'h', 'g', 'h', 'e']


# python >= 3.7 
dct_index = {j:i for (i, j) in enumerate(dict.fromkeys(a+b))}


# Older python version
dct_index = {j:i for (i, j) in enumerate(a)}
for i in b:
    if i not in dct_index:
        dct_index[i] = len(dct_index)

# dct_index : {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'e': 2, 'z': 3, 'f': 4, 'g': 5, 'h': 6}

print(sorted(b, key=dct_index.get))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ['a', 'c', 'j', 'r' , 'p']
b = ['b', 'c', 'a']

c = []

for i in b:
    if i in a:
        c.insert(a.index(i), i)

for i in b:
    if i not in a:
        c.append(i)

print(c)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you edit your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?